# A simple cout statement prints, a variable prints, a for loop will not print

Tags: c++, for-loop, printing, cout

This prints 100 and "counter is Active." but will not print any text that is associated with the for loop.

I have attempted this in Code::Blocks and Microsoft Visual 2010 Express (both with the same results).

Apologies if this is inane, I just started trying to learn C++ a few days ago.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int ram = 100;
    cout << ram << endl;
    cout << "counter is Active." << endl;

    for (int counter = 0; counter > 10; counter++)
    {
        cout << "counter is not greater than 10." << endl;
        cout << "counter is " << counter << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop conditions are wrong...

Change your loop to

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++)
```

Your loop was previously

```
for (int counter = 0; counter > 10; counter++)
```

Which says continue looping while counter is greater than 10. Since counter starts at zero, it is never greater than 10, and so the code in the loop never executes.